# How to reset Liferay? (delete all content/users/customizations)

Tags: mysql, liferay, liferay-7

I totally messed up my development Liferay (trial-and-error experiments lead to many wrong identifiers being written in many wrong MySQL rows/columns).

How to reset it, so that I get a fresh clean Liferay?

I want to get back to the situation where you have just installed Liferay, and there are no users, no customizations, no pages, no content.

I should take less time than reinstalling all of Liferay (Java, database, etc).

Comment: All you need to do it drop all the tables from the database. If the database tables don't exist when liferay starts up, it will re-create them on startup.

Answer (score 0):

1) Shut down Liferay.

2) Drop the database and create it again *(Example for MySQL. You can find the exact database name in a `.properties` file in Liferay's home folder)*:

```
drop database lportal;
create database lportal character set utf8;
```

3) In Liferay's home folder, remove the content of each of these folders:

- `osgi/modules/`
- `osgi/state/`
- `data/document_library/`
- `data/elasticsearch/`

Note: I suggest keeping the license folder, to avoid the hassle of reinstalling the license. It has always worked for me.

4) Still in Liferay's home folder, remove the files `portal-ext.properties` and `portal-setup-wizard.properties` *(or keep them if you have no added anything special to them, that will spare you from having to configure the database access again)*

5) Start Liferay again.

Comment: I didn't check if the license directory is specific to the database state. My script for recreation just always copies the license to the deployment directory.